# How to select and copy only numbers from selected element

Tags: c#, selenium

I need help with one small problem. I am trying to select element and copy only numbers and paste them to other location. Is there any way to use Selenium with C# to highlight only numbers in the element.
The element is located in "span id=lblMessage" and i need to select only numbers 1230272.

```
<div id="mainPanel"> 
<div id="jaxPanel">...</div>
<span id="UpdatePanel">...</span>
<div id="UpdatePanelMessage">...</div>
<span id="lblMessage">Message saved with number:1230272</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Split** method of C#

the text you are getting in your locator can spilt like below:

```
string[] tokens = str.Split(':');  // str is variable having your locator value
```

As your string is having only one **:**, the string will divide into 2 array index.
use below to get your number:

```
Console.WriteLine(tokens[1]);
```

Now if you want to convert into number as data type you need to typecast